# why doesnt my php code for post method work?

Tags: php, post, authentication

I have the following form in my `index.php` page

```
    <form action='login.php' method='POST'>
    Log in Here:<br><br>
    Username:<input type='text' name='User_name' value='username' onFocus="clearText(this)" id='fn'>
    <br><br>
    Password:<input type='password' name='_password' ><br><br>
    <input  value='Log in' type="image" src="client-login-buttonclient-login-button.jpg" ><br><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox"  id="checkbox" />
    Remember password</span></p>
    </form>
```

and I am posting the form fields to another php page called `login.php`

```
  <?php

    session_start();
    $username=$_POST['User_name'];
    $password=$_POST['_password'];
    if($username && $password){
    echo $username;
    echo $password;
    }
    else {
    echo 'A field is empty';
    }
```

But when I do this, it gives me the following error

```
 Notice: Undefined index: User_name in login.php on line 4
 Notice: Undefined index: _password in login.php on line 5
```

Why is the post method not working?

Comment: Take a look at the error! It says you have an undefined index `$_POST['User_name`] in login.php on line 4 and 5! Double check that file and be sure you entered everything in correctly. Remember the $_POST array grabs the values from the name attribute `name='User_name'`

Comment: do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you're really getting.

Comment: @djthoms I have checked it more than 20 times before posting it here,the internet explorer gives me a broken page and this error while firefox doesn't give an error and nor does it display anything

Comment: The error message is really referencing the same index on both lines 4 and 5?

Comment: That's strange, because the code you posted only mentions `User_name` on one line. So it's complaining about `User_name` on a line that doesn't use it?

Comment: @Barmar actually i left a line empty in the login php,try copy pasting the lines in an editor

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Line 4 uses `$_POST['User_name']`, line 5 uses `$_POST['_password']`. So the error message about line 5 should say `Undefined index: _password`, not `Undefined index: User_name`.

Comment: @Barmar yups i think i copied pasted a part from the first error and a part from the second thats y..i should edit it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that the variables are not being passed.  In order to bypass the error and still catch that a field is blank, utilize [`isset()`](http://php.net/isset):

```
$username = (isset($_POST['User_name']) ? $_POST['User_name'] : '');
```

This will check to see if the variable was passed and if so, then set the corresponding variable to that value, otherwise set it as '' (or another value of your choosing).

Answer (score 0):

try to put [`isset`](https://www.php.net/isset) in your if condition and let see

```
 if(isset($_POST['User_name']) && isset($_POST['_password'])){
            echo $_POST['User_name'];
            echo $_POST['_password'];
    }else {
            echo 'A field is empty';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php

    session_start();
    if($_POST)
    {
    $username=$_POST['User_name'];
    $password=$_POST['_password'];
    if($username && $password){
    echo $username;
    echo $password;
    }
    else {
    echo 'A field is empty';
    }

    }


  ?>
```

Comment: When submitting an answer it is best to describe the purpose of your answer.  This site is not intended to just provide the code for how to do this or that.  In addition, your answer assumes that if any POST variable has been set, then the username and password variables are valid, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: Thanks for your Advice RobB. I will be doing that from next time :)

Answer (score -1):

You need submit button to post your form or at least do that with javascript and use `isset()` to check if these post variables contains values first and then try to assign values.

```
if(isset($_POST['UserName']){
$username=$_POST['User_name'];
}
```

Comment: `type="image"` is a submit button with an image.

Comment: oops didn't notice that, my bad !